# Verbatim LaTeX content of an environment exported to an external file

Tags: write, technical-environment

Is there a way to export the content of an environment to an external file without blocking the action of the environment ?

Typically in the following example, I would like to keep the content of the theorems so as to produce a document containing only the theroems *(the 2nd document will be build by a Python or a Bash file)*.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Théorème}[section]
\newtheorem*{theorem*}{Théorème}


\begin{document}

I do not need to go oustide.

\begin{theorem}
    Here is the best theorem for ever... I want to go outside. $ok^?$

    \begin{center}
        The same is true for me.
    \end{center}}
\end{theorem}

\begin{center}
    I do not need to go oustide.
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you are going to use Python or Bash then it is probably the easiest to collect the theorems using one of those, by pattern matching the file for anything between `\begin{theorem}` and `\end{theorem}`. That saves you a lot of trouble trying to get LaTeX to save part of the input to a separate file.

Comment: Ok. Indeed I would like to see how to do that with (La)TeX ?

Comment: Just to make that clear, you want to typeset the contents of your theorems as usual, but also append their contents to an extra file?

Comment: Yes  That's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me modify a little your example and give some proposals to what you want (if I understood correctly)

**Proposal 1.** Using the **new** [scontents](https://ctan.org/pkg/scontents) package, saving the contents in memory.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Théorème}[section]
\newtheorem*{theorem*}{Théorème}
\usepackage[store-env=thmout,print-env=false]{scontents}
%\usepackage[store-env=thmout,print-env=true]{scontents}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

I do not need to go oustide.

\begin{scontents}[write-env=test-thm-1.tex]
\begin{theorem}
    Here is the best first theorem for ever... I want to go outside. $ok^?$

    \begin{center}
        The same is true for me.
    \end{center}
\end{theorem}
\end{scontents}

\begin{center}
    I do not need to go oustide.
\end{center}

I do not need to go oustide.

\begin{scontents}[write-env=test-thm-2.tex]
\begin{theorem}
    Here is the best second theorem for ever... I want to go outside. $ok^?$

    \begin{center}
        The same is true for me.
    \end{center}
\end{theorem}
\end{scontents}

\begin{center}
    I do not need to go oustide.
\end{center}

% Are you sure you want to write it in external files?
% ...better to leave them in memory :)
%\getstored[1]{thmout}
%\getstored[2]{thmout}
\end{document}
```

The output obtained is like this:

[image: output-hidd]

If we remove the comments from `\getstored`

```
\getstored[1]{thmout}
\getstored[2]{thmout}
```

the output would be like this:

[image: using getstored]

And if we change these lines in the preamble

```
%\usepackage[store-env=thmout,print-env=false]{scontents}
\usepackage[store-env=thmout,print-env=true]{scontents}
```

the output would be like this:

[image: using print-env=true]

In all cases we get the content of the theorem environment in separate files (`test-thm-1.tex` and `test-thm-2.tex`), but we can do this without the need to write to external files, it would suffice to put all the theorems inside:

```
\begin{scontents}
\begin{theorem}
   ...
\end{theorem}
\end{scontents}
```

and everything would be stored and displayed according to the `print-env=true|false` which can be defined globally as a package option or as a local option.

```
\begin{scontents}[print-env=true]
\begin{theorem}
   ...
\end{theorem}
\end{scontents}
```

**Proposal 2:** If you still want to handle everything in separate files, [ltximg](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ltximg) does the job (I assume you're using an update `TeXLive` and you have `perl`...yes `perl`). We just need to run the next line:

```
ltximg --imgdir=mythm --prefix=thm --srcenv --noprew --norun --extrenv=theorem -o test-out test.tex
```

In your working directory you will find the file `test-out.tex` with all the `theorem`converted to `\includegraphics`, in the `/mythm` directory, you will find the separate files `test-thm-1.tex`, `test-thm-2.tex` and `test-thm-all.tex` file containing only the extracted theorems. Of course you will have to remove `\includegraphics` or comment them in the file `test-out.tex`. If you want the images to be generated remove `--norun`.

Comment: Good answer. This will help me to do some technical stuffs just with LaTEX. Unfortunately I have the following error `Perl v5.26.0 required--this is only v5.18.4, stopped at /Library/TeX/texbin/ltximg line 2. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /Library/TeX/texbin/ltximg line 2.`

Comment: Update the Perl version on your Mac, then. https://www.perl.org/get.html#osx

Comment: (untested) comment the line in `ltximg.pl` and then run the script from your system. I don't remember the modifications to the `regex` I added since version `5.18`, but come on...version `5.18` is more than 5 years old. Update the Perl version on your Mac is the right choice.